# Chrome extension to detect URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make one chrome extension which when it detects a spesific URL to "push" the BACK button on chrome.

Currently im trying just to console log one phrase. But its not working
Can someone find my mistake cause i cant

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function( tabId,  changeInfo,  tab) {
       chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(tab.url);
       if(tab.url=="https://www.google.com/"){
            console.log("ok");
       }
});
```

maniftest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "gagle detection",
  "description": "detect google.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
      "tabs",
       "activeTab",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

I want it to run on the background so WHENEVER i open www.google.com it should post something to console.log.
And if it is posting what should i write underneath "if" so it can go to the previous page????

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @JaromandaX so what do your propose to do there?

Comment: @JaromandaX it takes the url of the current tab and it checks if it is the same with that in the quote it prints "ok" in the console....

Comment: @JaromandaX ok chill i thing its the code that check if the browse url has any URL inside... but im not sure cause i found it on some research

Comment: tab.url is rarely going to be exactly, perfectly, and flawlessly equal to your url (since google adds a few tags to the end).  Instead try tab.url.indexOf("google.com")>-1

Comment: For you first question, do something like what @ThouArtAmazing suggested or use a RegEx to match your domain. About your second question, from your background.js it could look like this: chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{code:"window.history.go(-1);"});

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios, why don't you use a content script? This appears to be exactly what is needed for the task and on the plus side it will only request access to the specified site, not the browsing activity on all sites (many people refrain from installing such extensions and rightfully so).